# Iterate over map and use the pair as reference parameter C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, auto

I have an `std::map`. and I would like to iterate over it and use the result as an argument to a function. The compilation seems to complain about my object being a lvalue, but I cannot figure out why it is considered as a lvalue.

```
void my_function(std::pair<std::string, std::string>& my_arg){
    //do stuff, modify elements from the pair
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> my_map;
// fill the map with values...

for(auto& element : my_map){
    my_function(element);
}
```

I could probably use an iterator to solve this, but I would like to learn how to do it the c++11 way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `value_type` of `std::map` and its iterator is `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` and not `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. In other words keys are always constant in C++ maps.

Answer (score 7):

`std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type` is `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`: note the `const`.  If you were allowed to modify the key within a pair, that might violate the invariant that the map's entries are sorted by key.  Since you used a different `pair` type, the reference can't bind to the actual object.

Answer (score 2):

For consistency (and esp. if you were to template it at some point), I'd define your function like this:

```
void my_function(std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type& my_arg){
    //do stuff, modify elements from the pair
}
```